# Default Annotation on every property jsr303

Tags: hibernate, bean-validation

I am validating the user input using jsr303. I was wondering if there is a way to put an annotation by default on all the properties of a class.

For example

```
public String getName();

public String getAddress();

public String getEmployerName();

public String getEmployerAddress();
```

Now instead of annotating all of them as @NotNull/@NotBlank, I was looking for a way if I can by default set this validation check across all the properties which return String. The only reason I am looking for something like this is, I think its easier to forget putting this annotation on any property and thus opening a bug.

I would really appreciate your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of ready-to-use solution for this, but you could use Hibernate Validator's API for [programmatic constraint declaration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api) for this purpose:

- Determine all fields/getters of type String using reflection
- For each of these fields/getters add the required constraint via the API

E.g. like this for the fields:

```
List<Field> stringFields = ...;

HibernateValidatorConfiguration configuration = Validation
        .byProvider( HibernateValidator.class )
        .configure();

ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

for(Field field : stringFields) {
    constraintMapping
        .type( MyBean.class )
        .property( field.getName(), FIELD )
            .constraint( new NotNullDef() )
            .constraint( new NotBlankDef() );
}

Validator validator = configuration.addMapping( constraintMapping )
        .buildValidatorFactory()
        .getValidator();
```